# How to change ListView selected item's background color?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

My `ListView` structure in xaml file is written below. In this listview, I am adding some list items. When I click on any item from this items the background color of selected item will be orange by default. I wish this selected iem's background to be black. How can I achieve this in xaml?

```
<ListView x:Name="LstMenu"
                HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"`enter code here`
                             Padding="10">
                  <Label Text="{Binding ListItems}"
                         FontSize="15"
                         TextColor="White"
                         HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                         VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                </StackLayout>
                <Grid BackgroundColor="Black"
                      HeightRequest="1"/>
              </StackLayout>
              </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I really wish there was a great cross-platform solution to this issue, but to date I haven't found one.  Here's a link to a nearly identical question from the [Xamarin.Forms Forums](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/62485/modifying-the-listview-highlight-color-colorcontrolhighlight-for-a-xamarin-forms-project). Using an Android project as an example, I typically achieve the effect you are looking for by adding a styles.xml file to the Resources directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <color name="CustomHighlight">@android:color/transparent</color>
  <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/androidsplash</item> <!-- must be lowercase -->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
  </style>
  <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorPressedHighlight">@color/CustomHighlight</item>
    <item name="android:colorLongPressedHighlight">@color/CustomHighlight</item>
    <item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">@color/CustomHighlight</item>
    <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/CustomHighlight</item>
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@color/CustomHighlight</item>
    <!--<item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>-->
  </style>
  <style name="ProgressBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"/>
</resources>
```

Note that I am using a sytem defined color (transparent) in this case, but you could reference or define any color you like.Then add a reference to the style in your MainActivity.cs file:

```
[Activity(Label = Constants.CompanyName,
          Theme = "@style/CustomTheme",
          Icon = "@drawable/icon",
          MainLauncher = false,
          ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait,
          ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
   // your code here
}
```

I don't have a handy sample for Windows or iOS, but the concept is the same; override a default style in the platform specific project.